# Grunt warning: No source files found

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I am trying to use Grunt for the first time. I think that I'm properly following the directions to install and use Grunt with a plugin (grunt-text-replace). (See, for instance, [Grunt's page](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) and [the plugin's](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-text-replace).) But I can't successfully run anything -- instead, I keep getting the same error. I've been checking my code against the instructions from both Grunt and the plugin, but I can't see anything I did wrong.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "brink-prototype",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.1.2",  
    "grunt-text-replace": "~0.3.2"
  }
}
```

And here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    replace: {
      src: ['components/bootstrap/less/navbar.less'],
      dest: 'build/',
      replacements: [{
        from: /\.box-shadow.*$/g,
        to: ''
      }]
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['replace']);
};
```

When I run "grunt" in the command line, I get the following error:

```
Running "replace:src" (replace) task
Warning: No source files found Use --force to continue.    
Aborted due to warnings.
```

I also tried this process with another plugin (grunt-regex-replace) and had exactly the same error message.

Where have I gone wrong?

UPDATE:

Here are the relevant parts of the file structure:

- project/

  - Gruntfile.js
  - package.json
  - components/

    - bootstrap/

      - less/

        - navbar.less
  - node_modules/

    - grunt/
    - grunt-text-replace/

I have been trying to run the command from the project/ directory, where the Gruntfile.js is.

Maybe the path in my `src` should be relative to something else? I don't know.

Comment: The error means that grunt can't find the source files where you've specified that they should be. Are you sure the file exist att 'components/bootstrap/less/navbar.less' relative to the gruntfile? Can you perhaps update your question with the structure of your files?

Comment: Updated above. I had thought the path might be the problem, but can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: That seems right. But I just noticed it says "No source files found", not "Source files not found"... Could it be that you have to you *have* to write it like `replace: { subtask: { src:... } }` as in the examples in the docs?

Comment: That solved the problem! I had missed the subtasks in the documentation (and they weren't pointed out). If you're looking to help further, though, I'm still having a problem: the output file has not performed the replace successfully -- something must be wrong with my regex. But it seems to work here: http://goo.gl/ZH5hf. Any idea what I'm missing this time?

Comment: That's a separate problem and should thus be posted as a separate question. Unfortunately I haven't used this plugin myself.

Comment: I posted the solution as an answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 1):

The grunt-text-replace plugin requires you to specify a subtask.

```
replace: {
  aSubtaskName: {
    src: ['components/bootstrap/less/navbar.less'],
    dest: 'build/',
    replacements: [{
      from: /\.box-shadow.*$/g,
      to: ''
    }]
  }
}
```